# UEFI Dual boot with two similar Linux OS (e.g. Fedora) on the same hard drive

Tags: linux, multi-boot, fedora

I want to install 2 Fedora OS on the same hard drive (to strictly segregate my work job from my personal activities). So I did two installations in a row with two similar partitioning schemes, but I do not know how to handle the UEFI boot. I don't know if I should have two separate '/boot/efi/' Fedora or only one? I tried both, but all result in on unique 'Fedora' lines  in the UEFI boot menu (well, 2 in fact there is also the 'Fedora rescue' but this is the same OS). How can I manage this?

Comment: Are you aware Linux can have multiple user accounts? Dual-booting for that purpose is overkill.

Comment: I am perfectly aware of that ;) unfortunately, my question is not on how to create two user accounts ;) you might now want to help me answer my original question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two separate `/boot/efi/` are ideal as this prevents one installation making out of sync changes with the other.

You can use Grub Customizer to edit the Grub entries titles (be VERY careful doing anything else) to get a distinction as to which install is to be booted.